# jquery autocomplete with outlook style

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how to make jquery autocomplete with comma seperated (just like in outlook)? 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This demo has pretty much that exact thing, except it uses a comma instead of semi colon: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: can I limit the input based on the available options? say if I type 'j' then it shows Javascript, Java. How can I limit the user to select from the options and not type another word? thanks